# How exactly SQLite database update primary key id?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Suppose I have a table `contacts`

```
  id        Name            Contact_No
-----------------------------------------
   1        abc                12345
   2        lmn                56784
   3        pqr                83654
   4        uvw                17637
   5        xyz                98345
```

If I **delete row 3** from database, what would be the `id` of rows following the deleted row?

And if I **update row 4**, will it be given a new `id` or the id of row 4 will remain same after updating database?

What is the difference between `autoincrement` and `autoincrement not null`? Official documentation says that it will degrade the performance and database will work slow. Is it mandatory to write it along with `integer primary key`?

I have read many stackoverflow answers and also read [SQLite Official Documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) but I couldn't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `id` is the name of your `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column.

If you update a row, it will never change its id, since it is still the same row. (that's the whole point of update).

Regarding the creation of new ids, everything is in the doc your linked:

Relevant sections :

### Without AUTOINCREMENT

> On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually the one more than the largest ROWID currently in use.

There is no strict rule, it can be implementation dependent. Usually it will be equal to `select max(id)+1`. In you case 6, but if you delete row 5, the id 5 can be reused. (But don't rely on this).

### With AUTOINCREMENT

> If a column has the type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT (...) the ROWID chosen for the new row is at least one larger than the largest ROWID that has ever before existed in that same table. If the table has never before contained any data, then a ROWID of 1 is used.

Adding `NOT NULL` to `AUTOINCREMENT` is therefore pointless.

In your case, the next id is 6, no matter how many rows you delete before that.

Answer (score 2):

If you just use `integer primary key` then any insert will use the current maximum `ROWID` (for which `id` is effectively an alias) plus one.  Thus deleting row `3` and inserting a new row will use `6`.  However, if you were to delete row `5` (leaving the maximum `ROWID` at `4`) a newly-inserted row would get an id of `5`.

If you care about id's not being reused, then you need `autoincrement`.  The reason this is slower (and advised against unless you need it) is that the *largest ever value* is kept in an internal table.  Inserts then have to read/update this internal table as part of their operation.  If `autoincrement` was used, then an insert after deleting either `3` or `5` would create a row with id `6`.

A normal update of row `4` would leave the id the same, unless you used `insert or replace` which effectively deletes the row and inserts a new one.  Such an insert would follow the same rules as above.